# IOS urban Airship. How to Handling notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, urbanairship.com

I am pretty new to this. I implemented the Urban Airship push notification and its working properly.  Now I need to implement how to handle a push notication. I would like to show a tab or when the user clicks on the notification.

Appreciate any help.

Here is the instruction from urban airship and I dont know how to implement `UAPushNotificationDelegate`.

> #### Handling notifications
>
> iOS handles push notifications received outside the application, but if a notification is received while the app is running, it is up to the application developer to handle it.
>
> The sample UI includes an implementation of `UAPushNotificationDelegate` that handles alerts, sounds and badges, however if you wish to customize this behavior, you can provide your own implementation:
>
> ```
> [UAPush shared].delegate = customPushDelegate;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You would listen for an app delegate method and handle the notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
        //do your handling here
    }
}
```

If you pass in custom json objects you would also parse it here

Comment: thank you. I will work on it tonight and let you know how that went